# Route files with vbscript from a .net handler back to asp.dll

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, isapi

We are migrating from asp classic to .net. Unfortunately they named all of the .asp files as .aspx so that they wouldn't lose page rank when they moved to .net. This means that IIS maps all .aspx files to asp.dll.

After changing the mapping back I was going to try have a handler grab the request then check if there is any vbscript in the file and then hand it back to asp.dll if it otherwise proceed to handle the request normally.

We are using IIS7.

I think it may be possible to use a ISAPI filter to this too, but then i would have to learn how to make an ISAPI filter for IIS7 (which is fine if there isn't a way to this in .net)

Ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: turns out we are going to sunset the asp, thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you would be better off to use the ATL Server support libraries and make an ISAPI filter.See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz4bx6(VS.80).aspx

Plus you really don't want to hit the aspnet_isapi.dll unless you know you need ASP.NET processing; why incur the hit?

Although I may not understand your question correctly... Are you mixing classic ASP and ASP.NET in the same application? If you have to share session state between the two this can be rather challenging...